# Преобразовать полное ФИО в сокращённое

Tags: javascript

Как можно преобразовать полное ФИО в краткое?

Например, результатом преобразования строки

```
Васильев Иван Петрович
```

будет строка

```
Васильев И.П.
```

Comment: `'Васильев Иван Петрович'.replace(/(.*?) (.).*? (.).*?/, '$1 $2. $3.');`

Comment: Насколько  я понимаю, эту строку нужно разить на массив, взять первые буквы, а потом склеить и вывести?

Comment: @olyasha можно и так, а можно и регуляркой как в примере выше.

Comment: Что должно происходить с такими именами, как "Алиев Искендер Али оглы", например?

Comment: Извините возможно за глупые вопросы,  я прекрасно это понимаю, но почему  регулярка, которая в комментариях выше  выдает " Васильев И.П.етрович" ?
@Yaant могу только предположить что "оглы" опускаеться!

Comment: попробуйте вот эту регулярку: `'Васильев Иван Петрович'.replace(/(.+) (.).+ (.).+/, '$1 $2. $3.');`

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое @diraria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба способа работают только с корректными данными, то есть со строками, в которых ровно три слова, разделённых пробелами.

### Способ с разбиением строки по пробелам

- Вызываем метод [`String::split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) у строчки, получаем массив длины три
- Элементы этого массива — строки, можем получить первую букву строки, обратившись по индексу, то есть `s[0]` это первая буква строки `s`
- Конкатенируем нужные строки (используя оператор `+` либо [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings))

```js
let source = 'Васильев Иван Петрович';
let array = source.split(' ');

// конкатенация
let result = array[0] + ' ' + array[1][0] + '. ' + array[2][0] + '.';
// или, используя шаблонные строки
// let result = `${array[0]} ${array[1][0]}. ${array[2][0]}.`;
console.log(result);
```

### Способ с [регулярным выражением](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

- Используем метод [`String::replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

  ```
  source.replace(/регулярное_выражение/, 'на_что_заменяем')
  ```
- `.` (точка) означает *любой символ*
- `+` (плюс) означает *повторить предыдущий символ один или более раз*
- `(` и `)` (скобки) означают *группы захвата*, к тому что внутри скобок можно будет обратиться в замещаеющем выражении как `$1`, `$2` и т. д.

```js
let source = 'Васильев Иван Петрович';
let result = source.replace(/(.+) (.).+ (.).+/, '$1 $2. $3.');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Молодцы конечно, но автор задал вопрос, не стараясь даже решить задачу, т.е. по факту дав лишь ТЗ, а такие вопросы и ответы к ним не приветствуются на ruSO.

Comment: @edem скажите, пожалуйста, какая разница старался автор или нет? SO это база знаний а не помощь конкретным людям

Comment: Как Вы правильно заметили SO это база знаний, а не биржа работников за плюсы к ответам.

Comment: @edem ну хотите я ответ общим сделаю, лучше будет?

Comment: Лучше будет, если в будущем не будете поощрять подобное поведение у пользователей. Правила же данного сайта придумывал не я. И причины для закрытия у вопросов, собственно тоже.

Comment: Путь автор вопроса и не привёл своих примеров, ответ очень хороший. Не просто приведён код, но и расписан синтаксис со всеми пояснениями.

Comment: @edem иногда людям нужны идеи. т.е. не то что решение но хоть его описание.

Comment: @edem, то есть вы считаете, что вопрос стоило закрыть по причине `Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии ...`?

Comment: @edem притом это не какая-то олимпийская задача, а просто "дефицит" знаний (языка программирования)